# Get Nearest Date in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have list of events so each event start date to end date so each event have list of schedules between events start date and end date I need to get only first nearest date I mean first event schedule date.

Here is my code

```
SELECT
  s.schedule_id, s.schedule_start_time, s.schedule_end_time, s.schedule_topic, s.Parallel,
  c.speaker_name
FROM schedule_table AS s, speaker_profile_table AS c
WHERE
  s.event_id='23'
  OR s.schedule_date LIKE '%2012-06-07%'
  AND c.speaker_id = s.speaker_id
ORDER BY s.schedule_start_time ASC
```

Here I get all schedules like this

> schedule1:2012-06-06, schedule2:2012-06-06, schedule3:2012-06-08

Here I need only schedule1 and schedule2 only I don't need schedule3 how can i get this please guide me

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, this should do the job (**EDITED**):

```
SELECT
  s.schedule_id, s.schedule_start_time, s.schedule_end_time, s.schedule_topic, s.Parallel,
  c.speaker_name
FROM schedule_table s
LEFT JOIN speaker_profile_table c ON c.speaker_id = s.speaker_id
WHERE s.schedule_date = (
  SELECT schedule_date
  FROM schedule_table
  WHERE
    event_id = '23'
    OR schedule_date LIKE '%2012-06-07%'
  ORDER BY schedule_date ASC
  LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY s.schedule_start_time ASC
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer your exactly understand what i saying but i check your query it same result

Comment: thanks again ok here we get only one schedule but 2012-06-06 have three schedule so when i run this query it show only one schedule only